# How can I draw a Hilbert Curve Fractal recursively using C# GDI+ Graphics and Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, gdi+, fractals

I am working on a project in which I need to use recursion to draw a Hilbert Curve fractal in a Windows Forms application in C#.  I must use GDI+ graphics for this, but I am new to GDI+ graphics.  Below is my entire code for the Form class that actually draws the curve.  At the end of this post, I have included photos demonstrating my erroneous output and the expected output.

The `DrawRelative()` function is supposed to draw the next line segment from the current [x,y] coordinates to the new [x,y] coordinates, which are calculated by adding the `xDistance` and `yDistance` values passed into the `DrawRelative()` function to the `xCurrent` and `yCurrent` class properties.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HilbertCurveFractal
{
    public partial class FractalDisplay : Form
    {
        public int MaxDepth { get; set; }
        public int CurveType { get; set; }
        public int xCurrent { get; set; }
        public int yCurrent { get; set; }
        public int xLength { get; set; }
        public int yLength { get; set; }

        public FractalDisplay(int DepthValue, int SelectedCurve)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaxDepth = DepthValue;
            CurveType = SelectedCurve;
            xCurrent = 250;
            yCurrent = 250;
            xLength = 0;
            yLength = 2;
        }

        private void FractalDisplay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            if (CurveType == 1)            // Run the Hilbert Curve Generator
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(MaxDepth, xLength, yLength);
            }
            else if (CurveType == 2)        // Run the Koch Curve Generator
            {

            }
            else if (CurveType == 3)        // Run the Sierpinski Curve Generator
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! - No Curve Type Selected.  Ending Program.");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void GenerateHilbertCurve(int depth, int xDistance, int yDistance)
        {
            //if (depth == 0) // Base Case
            //{
            //    return;
            //}
            //else { }

            if (depth > 0)
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, yDistance, xDistance);
            }
            else { }

            // Draw Part of Curve Here
            DrawRelative(xDistance, yDistance);

            if (depth > 0)
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance);
            }
            else { }

            // Draw Part of Curve Here
            DrawRelative(yDistance, xDistance);

            if (depth > 0)
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance);
            }
            else { }

            // Draw Part of Curve Here
            DrawRelative((- 1 * xDistance), (-1 * yDistance));

            if (depth > 0)
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, (-1 * yDistance), (-1 * xDistance));
            }
            else { }
        }

        // Create a New Paint Event Handler
        private void DrawRelative(int xDistance, int yDistance)
        {
            xLength = xDistance;
            yLength = yDistance;
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(HilbertCurve_Paint);
        }

        // Perform the Actual Drawing
        private void HilbertCurve_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Discover where the new X and Y points will be
            int xNew, yNew;
            xNew = xCurrent + xLength;
            yNew = yCurrent + yLength;
            // Paint from the current position of X and Y to the new positions of X and Y
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, xCurrent, yCurrent, xNew, yNew);
            // Update the Current Location of X and Y
            xCurrent = xNew;
            yCurrent = yNew;
        }
    }
}
```

The first photo (below) is the incorrect output from the Hilbert Curve function given a MaxDepth of 1.

[image: Incorrect Output from Hilbert Curve Function Given a Depth of 1]

The second photo (below) represents what I should be getting from this set of functions (given a MaxDepth value of 1 passed in).
[image: Correct Demonstration of Hilbert Curve Function Given a Depth of 1]

Because it seems like the algorithm for recursion is coded correctly, I suspect that I am not using the GDI+ graphics in the proper way, or my class properties are being updated/set incorrectly somewhere in the recursive calls.  What can I do to fix my drawing algorithm?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to have the curve as IEnumerable points from start to finish? In current code I cant see what actually gets drawn.

Comment: The biggest issue you seem to have is a complete misunderstanding of how the `Paint` event works, and perhaps C# events in general for that matter. You are adding a handler to the `Paint` event every time you want to draw a new line segment, but that's wrong for at least two reasons: first, subscribing to the event doesn't cause anything to _happen_, it just signs you up to handle the event if and when it's raised; and second, if and when the event _is_ raised, your handler will be called once for every time you subscribed, but using the latest values of the variables.

Comment: The right way to do this is to separate the `Paint` event handling from the curve generation. Your curve generation method should just be adding point values to a list, or something like that. And the `Paint` event handler should just _draw_ the points currently in the list (you can use [`Graphics.DrawLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose).

Comment: I don't have time to post a proper answer at the moment, but I'll check back in a couple of hours...if you haven't figure it out yourself based on these comments and no one else has posted a good answer, I'll go ahead and write something up.

Comment: I would start the whole curve generation from the paint event and __pass out__ the Graphics object `e.Graphics` to __each__ iteration.

Comment: _"I would start the whole curve generation from the paint event and pass out the Graphics object e.Graphics to each iteration"_ - @TaW: yes, that is certainly an appropriate alternative. I've included both approaches in my answer, along with a brief comparison of the pros of each.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/07/draw-a-hilbert-curve-fractal-in-c/) example, hope it helps.

Comment: @raidensan: thanks, yes...that helped me understand the algorithm the OP was trying to implement. With that knowledge I was able to incorporate their originally intended algorithm into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I didn't initially understand the implementation you have for generating the points for the Hilbert curve. I'm familiar with a couple of different approaches, neither of which look like that.

But, that's an entirely different question. Your main issue at hand is really just that you don't understand how the drawing mechanism in Winforms works. Briefly: there's a `Paint` event, which your code should handle by drawing what needs to be drawn. Subscribing to the `Paint` event doesn't cause anything to *happen*; it's just a way of registering to be notified when drawing is supposed to occur.

Typically, one would use the Designer to subscribe to the event, by navigating to the "Events" tab of the Properties pane for an object in the Designer (e.g. your Form) and selecting the appropriate event handler (or double-clicking in the empty box next to the event to have the Designer automatically insert an empty handler for you to fill in). You can also, when handling the `Paint` event in your own object, simply override the `OnPaint()` method.

In either case, the correct technique is to establish the prerequisites for drawing, then call `Invalidate()` which causes the framework to then raise the `Paint` event, at which time you can actually draw what you want to draw.

Note that between commenter TaW and me, we have suggested two different approaches to drawing: I suggested pre-computing all of the necessary data for drawing, and then just draw that when the `Paint` event is raised; TaW has suggested calling the recursive method from the `Paint` event handler, and drawing directly as you traverse the recursive algorithm.

Both techniques are fine, but of course there are pros and cons to either, having mostly to do with the classic trade-off of time and space. With the former technique, the cost to generate the curve is incurred only once, when the parameters for the curve change. Drawing occurs more quickly, because all the code has to do is draw the pre-existing data. With the latter technique, there is no need to store the data, as each new point generated is used immediately, but of course this means all of the points have to be regenerated every time the window is redrawn.

For this particular application, in practice I don't think it matters much. At typical screen resolutions, you won't be able to make out the features of the curve long before you start to hit the limits of data storage for the points to draw. Similarly, the execution of the algorithm is so fast that there's really no harm in recalculating the points each time the window needs to be redrawn. Just keep in mind that these are trade-offs you may have to judge more closely in other scenarios.

Okay, so what's all that mean? Well, when I converted it to something that used the `Graphics` class correctly, I couldn't get your implementation to draw a Hilbert curve, so I changed that part of the code to use an implementation I know works. You can find a detailed discussion on how this particular implementation works here: [Hilbert Curve
Concepts & Implementation](http://www.fundza.com/algorithmic/space_filling/hilbert/basics/index.html)

Below, I have provided two different versions of that particular Hilbert curve implementation, the first using the "retained" approach (i.e. generate the data, then draw it), and the second using the "immediate" approach (i.e. generate the data every time you want to draw the window, as the drawing is occurring):

**"Retained" method:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private PointF[] _points;

    private void FractalDisplay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    private void Redraw()
    {
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();

        GenerateHilbert(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, (int)numericUpDown1.Value, points);
        _points = points.ToArray();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void GenerateHilbert(PointF origin, float xi, float xj, float yi, float yj, int depth, List<PointF> points)
    {
        if  (depth <= 0)
        {
            PointF current = origin + new SizeF((xi + yi) / 2, (xj + yj) / 2);
            points.Add(current);
        }
        else
        {
            GenerateHilbert(origin, yi / 2, yj / 2, xi / 2, xj / 2, depth - 1, points);
            GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2, xj / 2), xi / 2, xj / 2, yi / 2, yj / 2, depth - 1, points);
            GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2 + yi / 2, xj / 2 + yj / 2), xi / 2, xj / 2, yi / 2, yj / 2, depth - 1, points);
            GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2 + yi, xj / 2 + yj), -yi / 2, -yj / 2, -xi / 2, -xj / 2, depth - 1, points);
        }
    }

    // Perform the Actual Drawing
    private void HilbertCurve_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_points != null)
        {
            float scale = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1 / scale))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, _points);
            }
        }
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

**"Immediate" method:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void Redraw()
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private PointF GenerateHilbert(PointF origin, float xi, float xj, float yi, float yj, int depth,
        PointF? previous, Graphics graphics, Pen pen)
    {
        if (depth <= 0)
        {
            PointF current = origin + new SizeF((xi + yi) / 2, (xj + yj) / 2);

            if (previous != null)
            {
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, previous.Value, current);
            }

            return current;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = GenerateHilbert(origin, yi / 2, yj / 2, xi / 2, xj / 2, depth - 1, previous, graphics, pen);
            previous = GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2, xj / 2), xi / 2, xj / 2, yi / 2, yj / 2, depth - 1, previous, graphics, pen);
            previous = GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2 + yi / 2, xj / 2 + yj / 2), xi / 2, xj / 2, yi / 2, yj / 2, depth - 1, previous, graphics, pen);
            return GenerateHilbert(origin + new SizeF(xi / 2 + yi, xj / 2 + yj), -yi / 2, -yj / 2, -xi / 2, -xj / 2, depth - 1, previous, graphics, pen);
        }
    }

    // Perform the Actual Drawing
    private void HilbertCurve_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float scale = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1 / scale))
        {
            GenerateHilbert(new PointF(), 1, 0, 0, 1, (int)numericUpDown1.Value, null, e.Graphics, pen);
        }
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

In both examples I've made some other changes which are not strictly needed for the purpose of illustrating the techniques, but which are still useful:

- The curve itself is computed in unit space (i.e. a square of side length of 1), and then drawn by scaling the drawing to fit the window.
- Where it makes sense, individual coordinates are passed as whole `PointF` values instead. This simplifies reuse of the values and adding new offsets to the X and Y values.
- Since the drawing is now scaled to the window, the window is redrawn if its size changes.
- For simplicity, this `Form` is self-contained, with a `NumericUpDownControl` that determines the recursion depth. I didn't include instantiation of this control; I presume you can add the appropriate control yourself in the Designer, to make the above compile.

**Addendum:**

I've had a chance to look over the other examples on the Internet of the algorithm that you tried to implement. Now that I understand what the basic mechanism of the algorithm is, I was able to fix your version so that it works (the main problem was that you were using instance fields to store the deltas for the algorithm, but also using the same fields to initialize the algorithm, so once the algorithm ran once, subsequent executions wouldn't work). So for the sake of completeness, here is a second "retained" version of the code, using your preferred algorithm instead of the one I used above:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private PointF _previousPoint;
    private PointF[] _points;

    private void FractalDisplay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    private void Redraw()
    {
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();

        // Start here, to provide a bit of margin within the client area of the window
        _previousPoint = new PointF(0.025f, 0.025f);
        points.Add(_previousPoint);

        int depth = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        float gridCellCount = (float)(Math.Pow(2, depth) - 1);

        // Use only 95% of the available space in the client area. Scale
        // the delta for drawing to fill that 95% width/height exactly,
        // according to the number of grid cells the given depth will
        // produce in each direction.
        GenerateHilbert3(depth, 0, 0.95f / gridCellCount, points);
        _points = points.ToArray();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void GenerateHilbert(int depth, float xDistance, float yDistance, List<PointF> points)
    {
        if (depth < 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        GenerateHilbert(depth - 1, yDistance, xDistance, points);
        DrawRelative(xDistance, yDistance, points);
        GenerateHilbert(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance, points);
        DrawRelative(yDistance, xDistance, points);
        GenerateHilbert(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance, points);
        DrawRelative(-xDistance, -yDistance, points);
        GenerateHilbert(depth - 1, -yDistance, -xDistance, points);
    }

    private void DrawRelative(float xDistance, float yDistance, List<PointF> points)
    {
        // Discover where the new X and Y points will be
        PointF currentPoint = _previousPoint + new SizeF(xDistance, yDistance);

        // Paint from the current position of X and Y to the new positions of X and Y
        points.Add(currentPoint);

        // Update the Current Location of X and Y
        _previousPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    // Perform the Actual Drawing
    private void HilbertCurve_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_points != null)
        {
            float scale = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1 / scale))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, _points);
            }
        }
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

As before, I've modified your implementation slightly, so that the drawing is scaled to fit within the window at all depths. This involves drawing into the unit square and then setting the transform appropriately according to the window size.

In addition to fixing the basic usage of `Graphics`, and the issue with the `xLength` and `yLength` fields, I also fixed a minor bug in your code (where you were recursing one level too deep) and cleaned up the recursion a bit (there's no need to repeat the depth check…just do it once, at the beginning of the recursive method).

It is of course possible to implement this in the "immediate" style as well. I think between this new code example, and the "immediate" method example above, I can leave that exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Nice. And so much shorter.

Comment: @Peter Duniho - Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.  I admit that I am a student still learning the features of C# and specifically I do not have much experience using event handlers in C#.  The whole concept of GDI+ graphics is new to me as well.  I was working off of a pseudocode implementation of the Hilbert Curve from _Essential Algorithms_ by Rod Stephens, though I may have missed something.  Thanks once again.

Comment: @TechAust10: glad I was able to help. Learning a new programming language _and_ a new graphics API at the same time can certainly be daunting. :) Thanks to the link provided by someone else in the comments to your question, I was able to better understand the algorithm you were trying to use, and then to write a working example based on that approach instead of the algorithm I used earlier. Please see the above edit for those details.

Comment: @Peter Duniho - I appreciate all of your help.  I will take your advice and attempt to edit my code based on your example.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fractal generator I came up with after heeding the advice of @Peter Duniho - The code shown does not include the form that actually gets the depth level (maxDepth) of recursion requested by the user.

```
public partial class HilbertDisplay : Form
    {
        private int maxDepth;
        private int xCurrent = 0;
        private int yCurrent = 0;
        private int xNew = 0;
        private int yNew = 0;

        public HilbertDisplay(int depthEntered)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            maxDepth = depthEntered;
        }

        private void HilbertDisplay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Update();
        }

        // Perform the Drawing
        private void HilbertDisplay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Run the Hilbert Curve Generator
            // Use a line segment length of 10 for Y
            GenerateHilbertCurve(maxDepth, 0, 10, e);
        }

        // The Recursive Hilbert Curve Generator
        private void GenerateHilbertCurve(int depth, int xDistance, int yDistance, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (depth < 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, yDistance, xDistance, e);

                // Paint from the current position of X and Y to the new positions of X and Y
                FindPointRelative(xDistance, yDistance);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, xCurrent, yCurrent, xNew, yNew);  // Draw Part of Curve Here
                UpdateCurrentLocation();

                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance, e);

                // Paint from the current position of X and Y to the new positions of X and Y
                FindPointRelative(yDistance, xDistance);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, xCurrent, yCurrent, xNew, yNew);   // Draw Part of Curve Here
                UpdateCurrentLocation();

                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, xDistance, yDistance, e);

                // Paint from the current position of X and Y to the new positions of X and Y
                FindPointRelative(-xDistance, -yDistance);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, xCurrent, yCurrent, xNew, yNew);   // Draw Part of Curve Here
                UpdateCurrentLocation();

                GenerateHilbertCurve(depth - 1, (-1 * yDistance), (-1 * xDistance), e);
            }
        }

        private void FindPointRelative(int xDistance, int yDistance)
        {
            // Discover where the new X and Y points will be
            xNew = xCurrent + xDistance;
            yNew = yCurrent + yDistance;
            return;
        }

        private void UpdateCurrentLocation()
        {
            // Update the Current Location of X and Y
            xCurrent = xNew;
            yCurrent = yNew;
            return;
        }
    }
```

This code, unlike that of @Peter Duniho, does not account for the form's size.  This depicts a Hilbert Curve fractal up to a recursion depth of 6 or 7 on my laptop (due to limitations on window size made by my laptop screen size/resolution).

I know that my solution is not as elegant as that of @Peter Duniho, but as this is for an assignment I did not want to simply copy his code.  I made edits based on his suggestions, especially in regard to the `Paint` event.